# How to popup a dialog box in c++ wxidgets using main() not init()

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, dialog

I am popuping a dialogbox from displaying logs using wxwidgets of c++, which contains init() for initialization. i want to know that can init() is necessary to popup a dialog or same can be done using only main() only in c++. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lengthy discussion on how to initialize a wx-application from a custom main routine here: [wxApp without Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208373/wxwidgets-how-to-initialize-wxapp-without-using-macros-and-without-entering-the)

from my experience i can tell you that it is ok to show modal dialogs (e.g. `wxMessageDialog::ShowModal`) in the `wxApp::OnInit` implementation.

this is just a quess but, using the information provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208373/wxwidgets-how-to-initialize-wxapp-without-using-macros-and-without-entering-the) above you should be able to show modal dialogs after calling:

```
   wxApp::SetInstance( new MyWxApp() );
   wxEntryStart( argc, argv );
```

Comment: do not forget the cleaup if you do this: `void wxEntryCleanup()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a dialog box:
[wxMessageDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_message_dialog.html)

Or a Splash Screen:  [wxSplashScreen](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxsplashscreen.html)

You could always use the underlying OS API to draw your own windows; although that may take a lot of setup.

Comment: messagebox for displaying logs. just want to know that always use init() instead of main() for dialogs,frames and panels etc ect,..

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand your question.

I am guessing you are asking about WHERE to call the constructor and other methods of the controls you want to create.  This is best answered by looking at the sample applications that come with the wxWidgets distribution.

You should not call anything from the main()function of your program.  You should call the constructor for your top level frame fromthe wxAPP method Init().  The rest should probably be called from the top level window constructor and its methods.  It is hard to answer these questions in general.  Please look at the sample code to see how things are done.

Comment: ok thank you..but my question is simple that can i use only main() insead of init() for popup the dilaogbox in c++ through wxwidgets.