# Standalone FileDialog window with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use wxWidgets to create a open/save FileDialog window in a cross-platform way. So I've looked at the examples in [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_dialog.html). I also want to create standalone windows, with no parent, because I am not using any other instance of a wxApp/wxWindow elsewhere in my program.

Additionally, I need to have my own `main` function, so I don't want to use a macro such as `IMPLEMENT_APP`. I tried to follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208373/wxwidgets-how-to-initialize-wxapp-without-using-macros-and-without-entering-the), and came up with the following minimal program:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string openFile() {
    wxFileDialog openFileDialog(NULL,  _("Open XYZ file"), "", "",
        "XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz", wxFD_OPEN|wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST);

    if (openFileDialog.Show() == wxID_CANCEL)
        return ""; // the user changed idea...

    // proceed loading the file chosen by the user;
    return "something";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << wxEntryStart(argc, argv) << std::endl;
    std::string s = openFile();
    wxEntryCleanup();
}
```

And here is the CMakeLists.txt I used to compile the code:

```
CMake_Minimum_Required(VERSION 2.8.11)
Project(test)

Find_Package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
Include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

Add_Executable(test main.cpp)
Target_Link_Libraries(test ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Still, when I run this program, I get a *Segmentation Fault*, despite the `wxEntryStart` returning `true`, and I have no idea where the problem comes from. Any tip?

Comment: Start by building a debug version and run in a debugger to see *where* the crash happens.

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore if I precede the call to `wxEntryStart` by a line that contains `wxApp::SetInstance( new wxApp() );`. However when I run the program no window is prompted, and the `openFileDialog.Show()` line returns immediately (`openFile` returns `"something"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be so bold with stripping down wx's initialization code. It may work today, but in the next version, who knows...

This is what I use:

```
class MyApp : public wxApp { };
wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(MyApp);

int main()
{
    wxDISABLE_DEBUG_SUPPORT();
    int dummy = 0;
    if(!wxEntryStart(dummy, static_cast<wxChar**>(nullptr)))
        return 1;
    auto onx1 = on_exit([]{ wxEntryCleanup(); }); //using RAII for cleanup

    //Other initialization, create main window, show it.

    wxGetApp().OnRun(); //This starts the event loop.
    //In your case, it looks like ShowModal's event loop is enough, 
    //so you don't need this.
}
```

I think those macros, ugly as they are, provide much better insulation against future changes in the library initialization code.

Comment: Do we need wxDECLARE_APP if we use wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN in the same file? Can we use wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(wxApp) and avoid declaring our own child app class?

Comment: @skuld You're right, `wxDECLARE_APP` only declares `wxGetApp()`, which is also defined in the other macro. I guess it should also work with wxApp, but I prefer to keep things as close to the 'official' way of doing things as possible. Once I accepted a couple of ugly macros in a file, one more empty class definition is no big deal.

Comment: I'll remove `wxDECLARE_APP()` from the code sample, for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Sounds good to me. However I'll stick with using `wxApp` instead of `MyApp`, as the documentation doesn't advise against that. I'll change my mind in the future if I see I need a `MyApp` child class, albeit I don't see what could possibly work with an empty `MyApp` and be broken when using the base class instead.

Comment: @skuld I, too, tend to think you'll be alright with `wxApp`, but a way for it to break in the future would be to have double definitions introduced by some macro in wx. For example, let's say a default version of a function would be defined in the wx code, taking a parameter of type `wxApp`, and then a wx macro would define a new one based on the app name you passed in; if you passed in `wxApp`, you'd suddenly have duplicate definitions. I'll be the first to say this is a highly unlikely scenario, but that's what I was thinking when I left that `MyApp` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some fiddling here is a code sample that works for me. Comments welcome on what'd be the best practices. What I did was keep `ShowModal()` instead of `Show()` in the `openFile` function. I also created the instance of singleton `wxApp`. The final code is here:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string openFile() {
    wxFileDialog openFileDialog(NULL,  _("Open XYZ file"), "", "",
        "XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz", wxFD_OPEN|wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST);

    if (openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_CANCEL)
        return ""; // the user changed idea...

    // proceed loading the file chosen by the user;
    return "something";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    wxApp::SetInstance( new wxApp() );
    wxEntryStart(argc, argv);
    std::string s = openFile();
    wxEntryCleanup();
}
```

Not sure this is completely leak-free, as `valgrind` seems to complain a little after exit. Any tip about whether I could also put the `wxEntryStart()` in the `openFile()` function welcome (I am guaranteed that this is the only place where the wxWidgets lib is used, and I want an API as simple as possible).

Comment: Without knowing wxWidgets that well, the `Show` function probably needs a message loop running to work, while `ShowModal` contains it own message loop for its own window.