# wxWidgets without wx main program -- how to code?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to write a wxWidgets component of an app that is called by another part of the app, so that there is no wxWidgets main program. I am having some problems finding the correct sequence of calls.

As I understand it, first I need to subclass `wxApp`:

```
class TestApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit() override;
};
bool TestApp::OnInit()  {
    cerr << "app init\n"<<flush;
}
```

Then I need to do something like this when I want to start up wxWidgets:

```
    TestApp* app = new TestApp();
    cerr << "a\n";
    wxApp::SetInstance(app);
    cerr << "b\n";
    int argCount = 0;
    char* argv[0];
    if(! wxEntryStart(argCount, argv)) {
        cerr << "wx failed to start\n";
        wxExit();
    }
    cerr << "d\n";
    int res = wxGetApp().OnRun();
```

But it never calls `OnInit()`. Does anyone know what I should be doing?

*This question is different from [wxWidgets: How to initialize wxApp without using macros and without entering the main application loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208373) in that they **do not** want to call the event loop (so they want `wxEntryStart()`) but I **do** want the event loop (so, it turns out, I want `wxEntry()`).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wxWidgets: How to initialize wxApp without using macros and without entering the main application loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208373/wxwidgets-how-to-initialize-wxapp-without-using-macros-and-without-entering-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wxEntryStart()` indeed does not call `OnInit()`, only `wxEntry()` does.

So you can either use `wxEntry()` (which also calls `OnRun()`) or call  `wxTheApp->CallOnInit()` manually.

See here for details: [wxWidgets: How to initialize wxApp without using macros and without entering the main application loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208373/1274747)

Comment: Yes,` wxEntry` calls `OnInit()`. Thanks.